# Is there an archive like arxiv.org for agricultural papers?

Tags: publications, preprint, repository

Is there any internet archive like arxiv.org intended for publication of agriculture-related conference papers or similar?

Comment: I assume you know about biorxiv.org, right?

Comment: No, I didn't know about it. It is a first proposal, good for some plant biology related aspects. However, with the lack of a section dedicated to agriculture it cannot be considered a good answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Posting on biorxiv.org should be an acceptable practice. Did you try and they removed it?

Comment: I didn't tried, for sure it is good for some less applied subjects, but where I can post here papers about irrigation, soil tillage, phytochemicals, precision agriculture (remote and proximal sensing...), or some food production related arguments, such as enology (excluding nutraceutic, and chemical aspects), and so on?